# Minimization Problem on Graph Partition

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, optimization

Suppose we are given a biconnected undirected graph $G=(V,E)$. I want to partition the edges into any number of partition sets such that the largest (in terms of the number of edges) partition set is minimized. The constraints I want to place on the partition is that if I taken any MST from each of the partition sets, then these edges would from a graph which contains exactly one cycle.

[image]

As an example, in the image above we see a biconnected graph and to possible valid partitions. In this case the partition on the left would be preferred because the largest partition set has size 4, whereas in the partition on the right the largest partition set has size 6.

I am wondering what we can say about this problem at all.

- Is there a way to write is as a LP problem or a CSP problem? Or a different type of optimization problem?
- Can we classify the complexity of the problem in any way?

Comment: A quick observation: the only-one-cycle-from-MSTs condition is equivalent to saying that the number of partition sets should be equal to the number of shared vertices (where a vertex shared between $k$ different partition sets is counted $k-1$ times).

Comment: A connected graph has only one cycle iff it has the same number of vertices and edges. If there are $p$ partition sets with $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_p$ vertices, then their spanning trees together have $(n_1 - 1) + (n_2 - 1) + \dots + (n_p - 1) = n_1 + \dots + n_p - p$ edges, which should equal $n$, the total number of vertices. But $n_1 + n_2 + \dots + n_p$ is exactly $n+s$, where $s$ is the number of shared vertices. So $n+s-p=n$ tells us $s=p$.